# extract number from alphanumeric value?

Tags: javascript

how can we extract numbers from alphanumeric value, var source, destination; the distance from google maps comes with number respectively Km or Miles how to remove that aplhabets.

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
    new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': false });
});

function GetRoute() {
    var heathrow = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4711620, -0.4523710);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: heathrow
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var distanceMeters = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;

you can get the value in meters here without going further and km.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove all non-numeric values with the below:

```
function getNumVal(alphStr) {
    var newStr = alphStr.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,"");

    return newStr;
}
```

This function will output a numeric only version of whatever is passed in.

**Note:** This also keeps decimals